# How to convert physical address to kernel page structure inside kernel module (x86-64)?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, memory-address

How do I convert physical address to kernel page structure inside kernel module? (only for x86-64 arch).

following is what I have so far:

```
void *kernel_logical_address = phys_to_virt(physical_address);
```

Now, how do I get `struct page` for this kernel_logical_address?

Why do I need it?

In the kernel module I am working on, it maintains a list of free pages

```
 struct page *pages
```

I want to add this special page (the one points to physical_address) to this particular list. How do I do this?

Comment: Why do you need that? You should **edit your question** to improve it a lot (by adding several paragraphs), give some motivation and perhaps some [MCVE]

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, yes, just updated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use pfn_to_page(pfn_num) macro. Pfn num == phys_addr >> 12

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. there is no trivial way other than lock and traversal all mapped pages.

Because the same page may be mapped multiple time at different linear address or isn't mapped at all.